# Showing just a child DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show/hide fields depending on one parameter. The thing is, sometimes I want to show the two fields and sometimes just one of them.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="djform_row extra_fields">
    <div id="ex_fields" style="display: none;">
        <div class="djform_row">
            <label id="djisbn-lbl" class="label" for="djisbn">ISBN * </label>
            <div class="djform_field">
                <input id="djisbn" class="inputbox required" type="text" value="" name="isbn" required="required" aria-required="true">
                <div id="suggestions"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="djform_row">
            <label id="djautor-lbl" class="label" for="djautor">Autor * </label>
            <div class="djform_field">
                <input id="djautor" class="inputbox required" type="text" value="" name="autor" required="required" aria-required="true">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I show it depending on the category like this:

```
if(cat_id > 38){
    document.getElementById('ex_fields').style.display = 'none';
}else{
    document.getElementById('ex_fields').style.display = 'block';
}
```

But what I really want to do is, when cat_id > 38, show just the Autor fields.

I tried to set and id for div class="djform_row, diferent id's for both div's, but that did not worked.

How can I do that? Any advice?

Comment: Where are you getting cat_id?

Comment: In the same page. It is a select of categories.

Comment: Are you able to leverage JQuery?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not english, leverage?

Comment: Sorry, can you use JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Giving each .djform_row an id i thinks its a good solution for the problem, i let some code below:

```
<div class="djform_row extra_fields">
        <div id="ex_fields" >
            <div id="child1" class="djform_row" style="display: none;">
                <label id="djisbn-lbl" class="label" for="djisbn">ISBN * </label>
                <div class="djform_field">
                    <input id="djisbn" class="inputbox required" type="text" value="" name="isbn" required="required" aria-required="true">
                    <div id="suggestions"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="child2" class="djform_row"  style="display: none;">
                <label id="djautor-lbl" class="label" for="djautor">Autor * </label>
                <div class="djform_field">
                    <input id="djautor" class="inputbox required" type="text" value="" name="autor" required="required" aria-required="true">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
if(cat_id > 38){
    document.getElementById('child2').style.display = 'block';
}else{
    document.getElementById('child1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('child2').style.display = 'block';
}
```

I leave the **JSFiddle** here: http://jsfiddle.net/2xrNT/

Comment: Nope, I dont know why but that is not working. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Zariweya Please set my answer as the accepted one if it was useful for you. Thanks